# Clean up nodeJS function

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently writing an activity reporting system based on users; upon looking through a lot of files I'm noticing that I do a lot of `if` statements that clearly can be rewritten;

How would you improve this structure of file? I can then take any ideas/improvements from this file & apply them to the rest of the project.

Any improvements are welcome!

````
const conf = require('../../conf');
const globals = require('../../globals');
const ping_history = require('./ping_history');
const ConsumerAccounts = require('../models/Consumeraccounts');
const redis = globals.redis();

module.exports = active = {};

active.prefix = 'activeusers';

active.expires_secs = globals.secs('3 minutes');

active.payout = {
    amount_cents: conf.consumerportal.country_payments["default"].daily_cents,
    prefix: 'activepayouts',
    history_prefix: 'activepayoutshistory',
    threshold_secs: globals.secs('1 hours'),
    increment_secs_per_ping: 60
};

active.mark_installed = mark_installed = async function(uuid) {
    await ConsumerAccounts.findOne({_id: uuid}).then(result => {
        if (result.software_installed) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return result.mark_installed(uuid);
        }
    }).catch(err => {

    });
};

active.payout_increment = async function(uuid, cb) {
    let amount_cents, amount_owed, history_key, k, max_amount, ref, ref1, ref2, ref3, ref4, ref5, ref6, ref7, ref8, tally_key, v;
    let today = await globals.today();
    tally_key = [this.payout.prefix, globals.today(), uuid].join(':');
    history_key = [this.payout.history_prefix, globals.today(), uuid].join(':');
    await redis.incrby(tally_key, parseInt(this.payout.increment_secs_per_ping));
    await redis.get(tally_key).then((tally) => {
        if (tally && (+tally) >= this.payout.threshold_secs) {
            let history = redis.get(history_key).catch((err) => {
                throw err;
            });
            ConsumerAccounts.findOne({_id: uuid}).then((consumer) => {
                ping_history.add(uuid, today);
                //checks here!
                if (!consumer.payout_eligible) {
                    return cb(null, false);
                }
                redis.set(history_key, 1);
                amount_cents = this.payout.amount_cents;
                max_amount = conf != null ? (ref3 = conf.consumerportal) != null ? (ref4 = ref3.country_payments) != null ? (ref5 = ref4["default"]) != null ? ref5.payout_cap_cents : void 0 : void 0 : void 0 : void 0;
                if (typeof consumer !== "undefined" && consumer !== null ? (ref6 = consumer.questionnaire) != null ? ref6.country : void 0 : void 0) {
                    ref7 = conf.consumerportal.country_payments;
                    for (k in ref7) {
                        v = ref7[k];
                        if (k === consumer.questionnaire.country) {
                            amount_cents = v != null ? v.daily_cents : void 0;
                            max_amount = v != null ? v.payout_cap_cents : void 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ((conf != null ? (ref8 = conf.consumerportal) != null ? ref8.limit_amount_owed : void 0 : void 0) && this.payout_eligible) {
                    amount_owed = (function(_this) {
                        return function() {
                            let cents, i, len, ref10, ref9, x;
                            cents = 0;
                            ref10 = (ref9 = _this.revenue_history) != null ? ref9 : [];
                            for (i = 0, len = ref10.length; i < len; i++) {
                                x = ref10[i];
                                cents = x.amount_cents;
                            }
                            return cents;
                        };
                    })(this)();
                    if (amount_owed >= max_amount) {
                        this.payout_eligible = false;
                        consumer.mark_ineligible();
                        return false;
                    }
                }
                consumer.assign_revenue(globals.today(), amount_cents);
                consumer.record_event({
                    event: 'daily_payout_assigned',
                    amount_cents: amount_cents
                });
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('Consumer account was not found');
            });
        } else {
            console.log("We haven't hit the correct number yet!");
            console.log(tally + " - " + this.payout.threshold_secs);
        }

    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
        console.log("Error Getting Tally Key!")
    });
};

active.ws_ping = async function(obj, cb) {
    let expires_secs, ref, val;
    if (!obj.uuid) {
        return cb(new Error('Property `uuid` required'));
    }
    expires_secs = (ref = obj.expires_secs) != null ? ref : this.expires_secs;
    await this.mark_installed(obj.uuid);
    await this.payout_increment(obj.uuid);
    val = 'u';
    return redis.set(this.prefix + ":" + obj.uuid, val, 'EX', expires_secs);
};

active.ping = async function(obj, cb) {
    let expires_secs, ref, val;
    if (!obj.ip) {
        return cb(new Error('Property `ip` required'));
    }
    if (!obj.port) {
        return cb(new Error('Property `port` required'));
    }
    if (!obj.relay_ip) {
        return cb(new Error('Property `relay_ip` required'));
    }
    if (!obj.relay_port) {
        return cb(new Error('Property `relay_port` required'));
    }
    if (!obj.uuid) {
        return cb(new Error('Property `uuid` required'));
    }
    expires_secs = (ref = obj.expires_secs) != null ? ref : this.expires_secs;
    await this.mark_installed(obj.uuid);
    val = obj.ip + "_" + obj.port + "_" + obj.relay_ip + "_" + obj.relay_port;
    return redis.setex(this.prefix + ":" + obj.uuid, expires_secs, val);
};
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
active.mark_installed = mark_installed = async function(uuid) {
    await ConsumerAccounts.findOne({_id: uuid}).then(result => {
        if (result.software_installed) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return result.mark_installed(uuid);
        }
    }).catch(err => {

    });
};
```

Note that `async`/`await` is just sugar syntax for promises. Few key things to remember when using it:

- `await` "waits" for promises.
- `async` functions return a promise.
- Returned values from an `async` function resolves the promise it returns.
- Thrown errors inside async rejects the promise it returns.

Nothing is wrong with chaining `then` in `async`/`await`, the syntax is perfectly legit. I often use it to inline some operations. However, it's usually not needed. If you're going `async`/`await`, go all-in with it.

This could be rewritten as:

```
active.mark_installed = mark_installed = async function(uuid) {
  try {
    const result = await ConsumerAccounts.findOne({_id: uuid})
    return result.software_installed ? false : result.mark_installed(uuid)
  } catch(error) {

  }
}
```

---

```
active.ws_ping = async function(obj, cb) {

active.ping = async function(obj, cb) {
```

This is an anti-pattern. You're using an `async` function (which returns a promise that should inform you if the asynchronous operation succeeded or failed), but then you pass in a callback for the error.

Instead of passing in the callback, have the caller attach a `then` with the  callback as the error callback, or `await` the call in a `try-catch`.

```
active.ping = async function(obj) {

  // Throwing an error in an async effectively rejects the returned promise.
  if (!obj.ip) throw new Error('Property `ip` required')
  if (!obj.port) throw new Error('Property `port` required')
  if (!obj.relay_ip) throw new Error('Property `relay_ip` required')
  if (!obj.relay_port) throw new Error('Property `relay_port` required')
  if (!obj.uuid) throw new Error('Property `uuid` required')

  const ref = obj.expires_secs
  const expires_secs = ref != null ? ref : this.expires_secs

  await this.mark_installed(obj.uuid)

  const val = `${obj.ip}_${obj.port}_${obj.relay_ip}_${obj.relay_port}`

  return redis.setex(`${this.prefix}:${obj.uuid}`, expires_secs, val)
}

// Usage
active.ping(obj).then(result => {

}, error => {

})

// or
try {
  const result = await active.ping(obj)
} catch (error) {

}
```

---

Few other minor nitpicks:

- Not a big fan of "declare all variables ahead of time". What happens is cognitive overhead, you scroll up to know what's there/what you can assign to. Declare variables as you need it.
- Most of your variables are only ever assigned a value once. Use `const` for those variables.
- Use Template Literals to construct interpolated strings.
- JavaScript uses camelCase for naming. While your data could be snake-case due to its origins, use camelCase stay consistent on the JS side of things.
- For temporary variables in blocks (i.e. loops, ifs), use `let`/`const` within the loop block. This way, you're sure that the variable is scoped to that block, and never leaks out to the outer scopes.

Comment: thankyou very much! my main issue is trying to rewrite the `payout_increment` function; seems so clunky!